# PHP Laravel Sending email inside variable to Mail::raw

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I've been having this issue where I want to send a plaintext email to a user (me in this case) but the email adress is inside of an object I retrieved from the database. All examples using Mail::raw use a string but not a passed variable. Is there a way to do that?

Code:

```
Mail::raw($messageContent, function($message)
{
    $message->to($foo->email);
});
```

This is what I want, in essence. $foo is a variable declared in the function that this is in. I don't want to make $foo a class variable because I am only using it here.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: access the variable in the closure using `use` `function($message) use ($foo) { ... `

Comment: Ah let me try that! :)

Comment: Alright the 'to' part worked, what if I wanted to send it to a support email and add the user's email as 'from'? I don't seem to recieve an email then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Mail::raw($suggestionString, function($message) use ($follower)
    {
        $message->to('support@company.com')->subject('Suggestion')->replyTo($follower->email);
    });
```

When you reply to this message it's automatically sent to the email specified in `->replyTo()`